# Asterisk cron page/intercom script

Tags: cron, asterisk

Wanting to send a page/intercom message to a group of VoIP phones as specified intervals.

Is it possible to schedule asterisk to send a page/intercom via cron or some other method? What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is posible. Require above average level in asterisk internal work understanding.

Plan is following:

1. Do dialplan for intercom your phones(need support from phones/some headers)
2. Test it from your extension, ensure intercome is ok.
3. Create script to do new call for asterisk with one side Local/intercom_extension@intercom_context, other side Playback(your_message)

If you want try that yourself, read this articles

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Paging+and+Intercom

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out